# How to insert anchor inside checkBoxList's template in Yii

Tags: php, yii, checkboxlist

Is any solution? I use

```
template'=>'<li>{input}<a href="/site/view/">{labelTitle}</li>',
```

how to place item ID inside href to make link like

```
href="/site/view/12"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `checkBoxList()` and `activeCheckBoxList()` template options are text and only accept below list:

- {input}
- {beginLabel}
- {label}
- {labelTitle}
- {endLabel}

it is not feasible, unless you override `checkBoxList()` method which is a method of `CHtml` class.

As a suggestion, use `checkBox()` or `activeCheckBox()` and populate them in a loop.